# jQuery: how to check focus on <select>?

Tags: jquery, focus

Trying to keep the element visible while user focuses on `<form><select>` inside of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/9v5ux/

This does not seem to work:

```
$('#toolbar form').not(':focus')
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do it.

```
    $('#toolbar').hover(
    function() {
    var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top == -115) {
            $(this).animate({top: '0'}, 300);
        }
    },
    function() {
    var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top == 0 && !$('#toolbar form select').is(':focus')) {
            $(this).animate({top: '-115'}, 300);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

`.not()` returns a filtered jQuery object, not a boolean.

You should write `if (!$(...).is(':focus'))`

Answer (score 0):

Code below does what you want. However you need to fix situation when element was focused and you click outside the toolbar so  mouseover handler doesnt fired.

```
$('#toolbar').hover(
    function() {
    var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top == -115) {
            $(this).animate({top: '0'}, 300);
        }
    },
    function() {
    var toolbarposition = $(this).position();
        if (toolbarposition.top == 0 && !$('#toolbar form').has(':focus').length) {
            $(this).animate({top: '-115'}, 300);
        }
    }
);
```